# Disadvantages of ExtremeDB

Tags: database, embedded-database

I searched google a lot but id didn't find any disadvantages of Extreme Db. Can anyone please give me 2,3 points regarding its cons ? I have seen its advantages , its indexing method its uses but can't able to see any disadvantage on any website. Please can anybody help my query ?

I have gone through this site but find nothing 
[website](https://www.theengineer.co.uk/supplier-network/product/scada-product-relies-on-extremedb-database-system/)

- pron and cons
- Indexing method
- maximum storage

Comment: What the disadvantages are depends on the usage case. Better check the specs in the source: http://www.mcobject.com/tech_spec

Comment: It seems you have not searched very long since even its Wikipedia article mentions some market reports and comparison benchmarks.